# Read And Write Mp3 File Android Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I want to download a song from an online server and save it in the device memory. Then recall the saved song from the device memory.
This is done correctly with the following code in Windows, but in the Android platform, only the file is saved correctly, but the file is not called and executed from the device memory and gives an error.

```
    private void Start()
{
    Adress = new WWW("**WebAdress**");
}
public void DownloadButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadMp3FromWeb());
}
IEnumerator LoadMp3FromWeb()
{
    WWW www = Adress;
    Adress = www;
    yield return www;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes((Application.persistentDataPath + ".mp3"), www.bytes);
}


public void LoadButton()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadAudioClip());
}
IEnumerator LoadAudioClip()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip((Application.persistentDataPath + ".mp3"), AudioType.MPEG))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        Musics = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(uwr);    
        myClip.clip = Musics;
        myClip.Play();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Www is a very old unity style and doesn’t look like you call it correctly.   The second half looks more promising but you aren’t checking it was successful so who knows.

Answer (score 0):

For loading the clip from memory you don't need to send WebRequests to the persistent data path. As that path doesn't exist in the web, it exists on your device only. use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` instead.

Comment: How can I put this line in my code?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to implement this method in the above code